# CSS different color for table each line

Tags: css, colors, html-table

I have this table with the following CSS formatting:

```
<table cellspacing="2">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>                            
            <th>Area</th>                            
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>${it.conference}</td>                                              
            <td>${it.accepted}</td>                                      
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
table {
    padding-left: 10px;
    width:90%;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:left;
}

th, td {
    padding:5px 10px;
}

th {
    color:#666666;
    border-top:2px solid #b7ddf2;
    background-color:#ebf4fb;
}
```

How can i apply individual css modifications for each line (for example, I would like to change the color of 'Name', without messing up with the other lines formatting, which means, only modify that one. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a CSS only method you'll need to add some class to the line you would like to style, like this:

```
<table cellspacing="2">
      <tbody><tr>
         <th class="color1">Name</th>                            
         <th>Area</th>                            
     </tr>
        <td>${it.conference}</td>                                              
        <td>${it.accepted}</td>                                      
     </tr></tbody>
    </table>
```

and then style it:

```
.color1 {
   background-color: (somecolor);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for something similar to the [nth-child CSS pseudo-class](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)?

If you want a more fine grain control over each individual one you might want to consider applying classes to them and styling them differently.

Edit: Here are [a few examples](http://www.virtualrevolution.net/fbin/tables/css3-table-striping.html) of nth-child.

Comment: Be aware that this isn't completely cross browser yet. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3Anth-child#section_6

Comment: @Nathan Thanks, yeah it's CSS3 so it's still relatively new and supported in more recent browser releases

Answer (score 1):

To style "Even" & "Odd" rows then use CSS3 
like:

```
tr:nth-child(odd){
    background:#999;}

tr:nth-child(even){
    background:#f5f5f5;}
```

Comment: was good, how to make this only effect on one table as i have many tables on my page so this effect on all of them how to make it exact one table only???

Comment: @WelcomeAlways, give your table an ID or class, and use it like `#table_ID tr:nth-child(odd){ //styles here }`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, at least for CSS3 :) really simple and works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

apply a class to whatever element you want, and CSS style it. http://jsfiddle.net/robx/wzXAJ/
IE: apply `<th class="name">Name</th>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away without support for IE 7 and 8, you can do...

```
th:nth-of-type(1) {
  color: #c00;
}
```

Otherwise, add a class such as th class="whatever" and then...

```
th.whatever {
  color: #c00;
}
```

See a live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/GFPgB/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply CSS style based on the content of the element, that is not possible with CSS. If on the other hand you want to apply CSS styles based on their position, you can use the :nth-child(N) pseudo classes. For example

```
th:nth-child(1) /*for name*/
{
color: blue;
}

th:nth-child(2) /*for area*/
{
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old answer, but I made a fun example in Jquery, and maybe it will help somebody with their question.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ya3n2wa5/)**

It'll get all `<p>` elements from the `document` and will loop through them, as jquery does that, it will add a CSS style to every `<p>` element on the page.